# SQL Server function to a get particular date and month regardless year

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am trying to write a if block statement.

The criteria is I want to perform a specific action when user inputs a specific date like Feb 14 which is valentine's day. But the year shouldn't matter. I don't want the condition to be bounded by year.

e.g.

```
 @UserDate SMALLDATETIME

IF(@UserDate='2015/02/14')
Begin
    Some expression
End
Else
    Some other expression
```

Comment: "when user inputs" doesn't sound like SQL, it sounds like you're actually trying to implement something in a programming language. Generally, IF/ELSE are very atypical approaches for databases.

Comment: Great, you removed the sql-server tag, but did not add the tag for the sql implementation you're actually using.

Comment: What did you try so far? Have you read the documentation to your SQL implementation?

Comment: @amalsom: OP removed the sql-server tag because it didn't apply. Don't add it back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `DATEPART` function to extract the month and day corresponding to Valentine's Day:

```
DECLARE @UserDate SMALLDATETIME
IF(DatePart(mm, @UserDate) = 2 AND DatePart(dd, @UserDate) = 14)
BEGIN
    /* some expression */
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, since you've finally added the TSQL tag, I was able to do a small [search](https://www.google.de/search?q=tsql+if+else).

Microsoft has documented these quite [well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx), so here's but an excerpt. You'd probably want to write a *stored procedure* that does your conditional thing and `INSERT`s the resulting data:

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> IF Boolean_expression 
>      { sql_statement | statement_block } 
> [ ELSE 
>      { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
>
> Boolean_expression
>
> ```
> Is an expression that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If the Boolean expression contains a `SELECT` statement, the `SELECT` statement must
> ```
>
> be enclosed in parentheses.
>
> ```
> { sql_statement| statement_block }
> ```
>
> Is any Transact-SQL statement or statement grouping as defined by
>   using a statement block. Unless a statement block is used, the `IF` or
>   `ELSE` condition can affect the performance of only one Transact-SQL
>   statement.
>
> ```
> To define a statement block, use the control-of-flow keywords `BEGIN` and `END`.
> ```

**EDIT:** Doing yet another incredibly complex [google search](https://www.google.de/search?q=tsql+date+operation) I've found `DATEPART` to match your problem very well.

Comment: yes. thanks for the documentation. But i just want to know is it possible to extact only month and day from the user's date like '02/14'

Comment: @AnujTamrakar: added that info, but really, Google is your friend.

Comment: @AnujTamrakar Yes it is definitely possible, q.v. the DATEPART function which can extract many parts of the input date.